# E-mail intent is not accepting HTML href tag

Tags: android, html, android-intent, gmail

I'm trying to forward message from my App to available email apps on phone. Message is formatted in HTML and at the end is hyperlink text, but this part is for some reason sent like plain text without clickable link. I tried Yahoo Email app and Gmail, both have same results. I also tried to use `Intent.EXTRA_HTML_TEXT` with empty `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` but email text was not sent at all.

Other HTML tags like `<p>` or `<br>` seems to be working fine. Only `<href>` tag is broken.

Code:

```
private fun sendToEmailApp(message: Message){
       val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
          type="message/rfc822"
          putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, message.title)
          putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, formatMessageHtml(message))
          action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
       }

       val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "\nShare with\n")
       startActivity(shareIntent)
}

private fun formatMessageHtml(message: Message): CharSequence{
      val emailTextFormated = addHtmlEndLine(message.text)
      return emailTextFormated.formatToHtml()
}

private fun addHtmlEndLine(messageHtml: String): String{
       val htmlUrl = "<a href=https://www.somewebsite.com/application/>mobile app</a>"
       val htmlEndline = "<br><p>Sent from $htmlUrl.</p>"
       return messageHtml.plus(htmlEndline)
}
```

Text (raw)

```
<p>Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, <br></p><br><p>Sent from <a href="https://www.somewebsite.com/application/">mobile app</a>.</p>
```

Text (sent formatted - sent to extra using `HtmlCompat.fromHtml`)

```
Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message, Test message,
    
Sent from mobile app.
```

What I wanna achieve is

Sent from [mobile app](https://www.somewebsite.com/application/).

Comment: Post your `message`. Nobody can test otherwise.

Comment: Plain text messages with http(s) urls are made clickable by the receiving side. Not by the sender.